# Mixpanel - authenticate issue, javescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mixpanel

I try to use 'Export Raw Data' endpoint with 'https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/'

But noting is work... 
I try a lot of request and liberty - no nothing work with the export end-point

my code:

```
    $.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors.now.sh/' + options.url;

  }
});

mixpanel_base_uri = "https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0" ;
proxy = "" // "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
  url : "" + mixpanel_base_uri + "/" + end_point + "/?",
    data: args,
    dataType: "text",
    processData: true,
    headers:{
      // "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : true,
      // "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
      // ('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(api_secret+ ':' +'')),
  },
    xhrFields: {
        // Getting on progress streaming response
        withCredentials: true,
        onprogress: function(e)
        {
          console.log(e)
            // var progressResponse;
            // var response = e.currentTarget.response;
            // if(lastResponseLength === false)
            // {
            //     progressResponse = response;
            //     lastResponseLength = response.length;
            // }
            // else
            // {
            //     progressResponse = response.substring(lastResponseLength);
            //     lastResponseLength = response.length;
            // }
            // console.log(response)
        }
    }
});

// On completed
ajaxRequest.done(function(data) {
    console.log('Complete response = ' + data);
});
// On failed
ajaxRequest.fail(function(error){
    console.log('Error: ', error);
});
```

I try to use 'node-mixpanel-export.js' and 'mixpanel-data-export' liberals but they isn't working

I get a lot of errors (every time different error)
from:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://data.mixpanel.com/api/2.0/export/?&from_date=01-08-2019&to_date=01-09-2019' 
 from origin 'http://localhost:8888' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
 Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

mixpanel_connector.js:129

and:

```
To authenticate your request, you must use your API Secret in the HTTP authorization header
```

event when I add the authenticate is still not working..

If someone can help me? or have code that works that I can understand

thanks.

------ UPDATE ------

I fix almost all the issue, but I can't pass the authorization issue, nothing is work.. maybe I miss something?

```
var obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var params = JSON.stringify(args);
  obj.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (obj.readyState == 4 && obj.status == "200"){
      console.log(obj)
      doneCallback();
    }
  }
obj.open("GET",mixpanel_base_uri + end_point);
obj.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64Encode(this.api_secret + ':'));
obj.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
obj.send(params);
```

I set the Authorization exactly like Mixplane guild: 
[image]

But still got the same error:

```
To authenticate your request, you must use your API Secret in the HTTP authorization header
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the Authorization.

By mixpanel:

```
To make an authorized request, put your project's API Secret in the "username" field of the Basic access authentication header. Make sure you use HTTPS and not HTTP - as our API rejects requests made over HTTP. Sending over HTTP can expose your API Secret.

Client Libraries
```

The issue was the "bota" func in javascript isn't return the right hash 
Just change it to other hash func